# Determining makeup of what constitutes folder Special Permissions

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to determine what makes up the "special permissions " option in a folders property in windows 7.

I can get the permissions of a folder using code in VB .net such as Read/Write, List Directory, Read and Execute...

But I don't know how to determine what the code equivalent of the check box you see in a folders permissions property box in windows 7 for special permissions.

Does anyone know what to test for that is the equivalent.

I want to display the properties of a folder in a windows form in VS 2010 that shows properties like the windows 7 GUI does.

Thanks.